# how to find mysql binary in redhat

Tags: linux, find, binary

I am working with a Redhat distribution.  The network admin is inaccessible so I have no ability to request information.

Using bash, how do I find the mysql binary so that I can run sql commands?

```
mysql -u user -p password
-bash: mysql: command not found
```

So they did not set up the path.

Comment: Are you sure MySQL is installed? Try running `find /usr /opt /home -name mysql`

Comment: Yes I am.  I can connect to it using an already establish workbench connection.

Comment: I meant the client, not the server, as your question mentions a problem with the client, not with the server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It usually should be in the path already and can be executed with just calling `mysql` in the shell.

If that's not working (and you have reason to expect the `mysql` CLI binary to be installed), you can try to find it with `find`:

```
 find / -name mysql -type f
```

Example:

```
find / -name mysql -type f
/usr/bin/mysql
```

Comment: Thank you - your `find / -name mysql -type f` worked.  I will mark your answer asap.

Comment: @AndroidAddict, where was it?

Answer (score 1):

MySQL consists of two components, the MySQL server which is the actual database engine and the MySQL client, used to communicate with the database server from the command line.

The MySQL client is installed from the plain `mysql` software package. If it isn't available (check with `rpm -q mysql`) use `yum install mysql`  after which the `mysql` command should available in your regular path or by it's default absolute path `/usr/bin/mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

Run the following command:

`which mysql`

Example where no MySQL binary is installed:

```
cwatson@thor:~$ which mysql
cwatson@thor:~$
```

Examlple where MySQL binary is installed to `/usr/bin/mysql`:

```
cwatson@cwatson-desktop ~/Desktop $ which mysql
/usr/bin/mysql
cwatson@cwatson-desktop ~/Desktop $
```

Typically though, if just running `mysql` from the command line results in "comamnd not found", then the binary is not in your user's `PATH`, or is not installed at all.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the mysql package is installed, e.g.,:

```
rpm -qi mysql
```

or
    rpm -qa |grep mysql

Note that the server itself is packaged as `mysql-server`.

If it's not installed, you will need to install the client, though this will require root privileges to do so:

```
yum install mysql
```